# How to get the total size of a SQL database using C++

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, mfc

**Problem:** I wish to use C++ code to get the total size of a SQL Server and/or Oracle database (preferebly in MBs).

**What I have tried:**
Currently, I am using `SQLGetInfo()` to retrieve information about the current database connection.  I pass in a `struct` which holds all of the database information.  I then use that struct to display the database information to the user.

```
//Used to gather information about the connected database
HRESULT GetInfo(DB_CONN_INFO &info)
{   
   SWORD cbValue;
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_DATA_SOURCE_NAME,
          info.szDSN, sizeof(info.szDSN), &cbValue);
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_DATABASE_NAME,
          info.szDatabase, sizeof(info.szDatabase), &cbValue);
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_DBMS_NAME,
          info.szDbmsName, sizeof(info.szDbmsName), &cbValue);
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_DBMS_VER,
          info.szDbmsVer, sizeof(info.szDbmsVer), &cbValue);
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_DRIVER_NAME,
          info.szDriverName, sizeof(info.szDriverName), &cbValue);
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_DRIVER_VER,
          info.szDriverVer, sizeof(info.szDriverVer), &cbValue);
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER,
          info.szDriverOdbcVer, sizeof(info.szDriverOdbcVer), &cbValue);
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_ODBC_VER,
          info.szOdbcVer, sizeof(info.szOdbcVer), &cbValue);
   SQLGetInfo(sqlc.g_hdbc, SQL_SERVER_NAME,
          info.szServerName, sizeof(info.szServerName), &cbValue);
   return S_OK;
}
```

From what I can tell, `SQLGetInfo()` has no way of determining the total database size.  Is there another way?

*I am using MFC C++, in Visual Studio 2010.*

Comment: What about a query like `sp_spaceused`?

Comment: Thank you @FlorisVelleman.  I have implemented sp_spaceused in my application and it works perfectly for SQL Server 2008.  I am still looking for a way to do the same in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use `sp_spaceused`. For Oracle you can get the size from the datafile: `select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 from dba_data_files;` (or `v$datafile`). This is the size of the tables (for log files: `select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 from v$log;`)